# angular's $parsers on input field is having difficulty on initial input

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex, angularjs-directive

I have the plunker link below for the full working element

http://plnkr.co/edit/Q1iZwBp6LXlun4yHs7Dq?p=preview

Here is just a brief code snippet to follow along with my question

```
var view_value;
function fromUser(text) {

    var return_value;

    if(text.match(pattern) === null){
    // if input is not the regex

    return_value = view_value;
    // alert("pattern not matched we need to reset input \nreturn value: " + return_value + "\nview_value: " + view_value);
    ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(view_value);
    ngModelCtrl.$render();
    }
    else{
        //  alert("pattern matched we need to continue \nreturn value: " + return_value + "\nview_value: " + view_value);
        return_value = text;
        view_value = return_value;
    }

    return return_value;
    // if your return value is same as initial passin then it ends
}
ngModelCtrl.$parsers.push(fromUser);
// parser gets fired when UI updates
```

Basically I have an input field, I also have a regex pattern, when something is entered i check this regex pattern and if it is not valid then i return to the last known valid state which means the UI UPDATES.  So invalid characters or characters that are not part of my regex can't be entered into my input.  This is all working fine as long as the first element you enter into the input is a valid character such as a number.  Then you can enter invalid or valid ones and it is working correctly preventing bad entries and allowing good entries.  So the only problem is when the first digit is an invalid character like say an 'a' then input is not getting reset.  This is because I don't have a last previous valid state yet.  It seemed that it would be obvious to just set my var view_value = ""; however this creates an endless loop.

So to restate, my input only allows positive numbers with a decimal point up to 4 digits.  If i type 4 then a it will remove the a, I could have 42.44335 and it removes the 5 etc so it is working if I type in a number the first time.  However if I start with a digit like a it should remove the a so the input would be blank again, however it does not do this so i am having problems with just the first initial input.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This fixes your problem when the first character is other than a digit, while also making the minimum number of changes to your code:

```
app.directive('inputRestrictor', [function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, element, attr, ngModelCtrl) {
            // changed here
            var pattern = /^(?:|(?:[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]{0,4})?))$/g;
            var view_value;

            function fromUser(text) {
                var return_value;
                if (text.match(pattern) === null) {
                    return_value = view_value;
                    // changed here
                    ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(view_value || '');
                    ngModelCtrl.$render();
                }
                else {
                    return_value = text;
                    view_value = return_value;
                }

                return return_value;
            }
            ngModelCtrl.$parsers.push(fromUser);
        }
    };
}]);
```